# settooltype method not found in motionevent

Tags: android

I want to automate the touch events like ontouch and double tap.

```
   long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;

        this.getWindow().getDecorView().dispatchTouchEvent(getMotionEvent(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN));
```

.

```
  public static MotionEvent getMotionEvent(long downTime,long eventTime,int eventType){
        float x = 0.0f;
        float y = 0.0f;
// List of meta states found here: developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getMetaState()
        int metaState = 0;
        MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
                downTime,
                eventTime,
                eventType,
                x,
                y,
                metaState
        );

    return motionEvent;
    }
```

.
    It is working fine and when I called this in background service
    this is what I got

```
     { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=0.0, y[0]=0.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_UNKNOWN, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=4827157, downTime=4827057, deviceId=0, source=0x0 }
```

ToolType is TOOL_TYPE_UNKNOWN . I want to set it to TOOL_TYPE_FINGER .
I have gone thourgh widgetevent.java file i fount getToolType method but there is

no setToolType method .
My question is Is it possible to set the tooltype if so how?

---

Remove - unwanted code formatter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer myself.
There is no direct method to update or change tooltype.But we can make one of the obtain to get motionevent object with desired tooltype.

```
public static MotionEvent obtain (long downTime, long eventTime, int action, int pointerCount, PointerProperties[] pointerProperties, PointerCoords[] pointerCoords, int metaState, int buttonState, float xPrecision, float yPrecision, int deviceId, int edgeFlags, int source, int flags)
```

we can make use of pointerproperties to change properties of motion event object.
[ref.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)